# Choosing OS X version for a mid 2011 Macbook Air 4GB

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

As I understand the matter, it is generally better to use a later version, however, I realize that the newer versions are really designed for more powerful hardware.  The MacBookAir4,1 in question is a dual core I5 1.6 Ghz CPU with 4GB of RAM.  It is currently running El Capitan.

The choices include:

- Mojave (latest, requires 2012 or later Macbook Air)
- High Sierra
- Sierra

**What is an appropriate quantitative test** to determine which of the three will run on the MacBookAir4,1 with a comparable performance to El Capitan?  While anecdotal reports are fine, any benchmarks to support a position should alleviate the issue of being 'opinion based'.

Comment: How is Mojave an option? You have a 2011 model, and stated Mojave needs 2012 or later.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer That's one option of how: http://dosdude1.com/mojave/

Comment: @gatorback If your computer is going to be connected to the internet, please note that running the newest, supported version is the only real way to go - otherwise you're risking your own security.

Comment: Benchmarks typically test CPU or GPU performance which only marginally is impacted by the version (or type) of the OS used.

Comment: I have almost exactly the same setup (it's a MacBookAir4,2, the 13" version of your machine). One reason I haven't upgraded to High Sierra is that Preview is much worse in High Sierra: it displays PDF pages twice, once in low res and again in normal res. Very distracting and annoying.

Comment: An 'appropriate quantitive test' would be to install Sierra, use it for a week or so. Keep important newly-generated docs separately. Clone the drive & move up to High Sierra, rinse repeat. I'd definitely say if you have to install a hack to install an OS, then there is some fundamental reason to not use that OS. [if this gets reopened, I'll flesh out to an answer.]

Comment: I am not inclined to push my luck by installing Mojave, unless someone out there confirms success with the same hardware.  A quantitive test implies measurement  (typically time).

Comment: There is no valid 3rd party 'quantitive test' as no-one else is going to be running precisely the same apps/services. The only valid test is to try it & see how it goes.

Comment: I am forced to add the constraint of a quantitative test because without it, moderators will label the inquiry as asking for opinion / subjective and put the question 'on hold'.  The goal was to determine if a newer OS would provide comparable performance or observable degraded performance

Answer (score 2):

I have a 2010 iMac and I'm running High Sierra. It has been running smoothly but my machine gets very sluggish sometimes when running Xcode. I can't compare it to El Capitan because it has been too long to recall. It has been as stable as Sierra though. I think the only issues you'd have would be due to having 4 GB of RAM. The size of the system would be very important, I'd think, for a 4 GB machine. I don't know the relative size of your system but there are many apps that will tell you the amount of free RAM you have. [iStats](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), [Monity](https://www.monityapp.com), and **SystemPal** from the app store are 3 such apps that will display how much RAM you are using and how much is free.

Comment: Thanks for stepping-up with an answer: please consider adding your hardware specs (CPU clock speed, RAM quantity).  Please clarify what you mean by `relative size of system`

Comment: I don't know much about your computer so I wasn't sure it the total RAM was 4 GB or if it had extra RAM just for the system.

Comment: It appears my machine uses 4 GB with no applications open other than menu bar apps of which I have many. The leads me to think the system may take s few GB of RAM.  Not a big deal with 16 GB of RAM  but may be crucial if you only have 4 GB. I'd try loading High Sierra and see how it does on your computer.  You can always change back to El Capitan.